# Find a sequence of Lipschitz continuous functions on $[0,1]$ whose uniform limit is $\sqrt{x}$.

Tags: uniform-convergence, lipschitz-functions, sequence-of-function

Find a sequence of Lipschitz continuous functions on $[0,1]$ whose uniform limit is $\sqrt{x}$, which is a non-Lipschitz function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_n:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f_n(x)=\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{n}}$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ and for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: $f_n$ are not Lipschitz continuous functions, take $n=1$.

Comment: $f_1(x)=\sqrt{x+1}$ is differentiable and $|f_1^{\prime}(x)|=|\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+1}}|\leq \frac{1}{2}$. Thus $f_1$ is Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: Oh, I see, but when $n \to \infty$, does this mean the bound $M \to \infty$, so that the function is not Lipschitz?

Comment: I got it that fix $n$, we can have every $f_n$ is Lipschitz. Thanks